# how to get N last records from rethinkdb fast?

Tags: rethinkdb, gorethink

Lets say you want to get 3 first records from rethinkdb. It is easy to do with:

```
objects = r.db("db").getAll(val, {index:"index"}).limit(N)
```

But in order to get last N records you have to get in count, count of objects and then do slice like this:

```
count = r.db("db").getAll(val, {index:"index"}).count(N)
objects = r.db("db").getAll(val, {index:"index"}).slice(count - N, count)
```

There is a huge difference in time:

First one with .Limit in golang takes: `63.28276ms`

Second one with .Slice in golang takes: `1.028439202s`

Doing `orderBy` some timestamp makes all thing even slower.

So as you can see it is just crazy from speed perspective. This query is executed on 26 000 documents in database.
I need some idea on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have tried many things and getting last `N` records will be slow so I approach problem different way. I am did some script that is putting last `N` records every `20second`s in `file/redis` and then I read that records from Go web app fast.